# adobe after effects animation preset duration

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm new to after effects. I want to apply some effect (for example flashing) to one of my images in composition. I want that effect to be applied from 5 to 10 second. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many answers to this.. heres one:

I'll assume you want the image to flash for 5 seconds then to be unaffected from then on.

- Select your image in the Timeline
- Search for 'Strobe' in the Effects & Presets panel
- Drag the Strobe effect onto your image in the timeline
- Observe the Effect controls palette which pops up
- At time 0, set a keyframe on the Strobe property 'Blend with Original' with a value of 0%
- At 5 seconds, set another keyframe on this property, with a value of 100%
- (modify the strobe to taste)

If any of this is unclear, I'd suggest the excellent free tutorial series by Andrew Kramer at:
http://www.videocopilot.net/basic/